# How to share variable between Gradle buildSrc and rest of project?

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle project that has a buildSrc directory. Both the main project and the buildSrc project need to know the URL of an Artifactory server. I would like to keep the URL in a single place, and I would like it to be kept in source control. I tried adding the URL to the gradle.properties file, but that seems to only get picked up by the main project, not by the buildSrc project.

How can I share a property between the two?

Answer (score 5):

To read project properties you can put at the beginning of `buildSrc/build.gradle` the following snippet:

```
def props = new Properties() 
rootDir.toPath().resolveSibling(GRADLE_PROPERTIES).toFile().withInputStream {
    props.load(it)
}
props.each { key, val -> project.ext."$key" = val }
```

Answer (score 4):

In Gradle, `buildSrc` is a [different *build*](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/allprojects_configuration_closures_not_applied_to_buildsrc), not just a project within the main project. So the easiest way to share properties, etc. between the main build and buildSrc is to put it in a separate `gradle/sharedProperties.gradle` file. Then your main project `build.gradle` can use

```
apply from: 'gradle/sharedProperties.gradle'
```

and `buildSrc/build.gradle` can use

```
apply from: '../gradle/sharedProperties.gradle'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to share information between the `buildSrc` build and the main build. However, you could read your own properties file from both (using `java.lang.Properties`).